# implement class object and Arraylist

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

I am new to Java and I have a task to do.

I have created a class (`Company`) which looks like this

```
 public class Company implements Serializable {
        private String companyName;
        private String companyCode;
        private int shareNo;
        private double closingRate;

        /**
         * Initializes a newly created company object so that it represents an      company basic information  in the program
     */

    public Company() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.companyName="";
        this.companyCode="";
        this.shareNo=0;
        this.closingRate=0.0;

    }
    /**
     * Constructs a new company object with the value of the passed in parameters
     * 
     * @param companyName - the name of company
     * @param companyCode - the three letter Code of the company
     * @param shareNo- the initial value of share issued by the company
     * @param closingRate- the price of the share rate of the previous day
     */
    public Company(String companyName,String companyCode,int shareNo,double closingRate)
    {
        this.companyName=companyName;
        this.companyCode=companyCode;
        this.shareNo=shareNo;
        this.closingRate=closingRate;
    }

    /**
     * Return the name of the company
     * 
     * @return the value of the attribute companyName
     */
    public String getCompanyName()
    {
        return companyName;
    }
    /**
     * Set the  name of company to a new value
     * 
     * @param companyName - new value of name
     */
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    /**
     * Return the code of the company
     * 
     * @return the value of attribute companyCode
     */public String getCompanyCode()
     {
         return companyCode;
     }
     /**
      * Set the code of company to a new value
      * 
      * @param companycode - new value of code
      */
     public void setCompanyCode(String companyCode) {
         this.companyCode = companyCode;
     }
     /**
      * Return the shares  of the company
      * 
      * @return the value of attribute shareNo
      */
     public int getShareNo()
     {
         return shareNo;
     }
     /**
      * Set the shareNo of company to a new value
      * 
      * @param shareNo - new value of share number
      */
     public void setShareNo(int shareNo) {
         this.shareNo = shareNo;
     }
     /**
      * Return the closingRate of the 
      * 
      * @return the value of attribute closingRate
      */
     public double getClosingRate()
     {
         return closingRate;
     }
     /**
      * Set the closing rate of company to a new value referring to the previous day
      * 
      * @param description - new value of description
      */
     public void setClosingRate(double closingRate) {
         this.closingRate = closingRate;
     }

     /**
      * Return a String representation of the object in a presentable format
      * 
      * @return a String representation of the object
      */
     public String toString() //@override
     {
         return "Company Code: " + companyCode + 
                 "\nCompany Name: " + companyName +
                 "\nNumber of Shares: " + shareNo +
                 "\nClosing Rate: " +closingRate;
     }

}
```

And I have main program from which I will be getting all the required parameters to this class.

Now what i want is to store this company data like name, code, shareno and closing price in a ArrayList, and then write to a file.

I tried something like this but cant understand.

```
public class Companydes {

    private ArrayList<Company> companyinfo; 
    public Companydes()
    {
        companyingo = new ArrayList<Company>();
    }
}
```

and got stuck. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: why do you want to store it in an arraylist? are you storing more than one company? Otherwise I believe what you're trying to do is serialization and then simply write the serialized object to file..

Comment: yes i want to store at list 8 companies

Comment: I believe this will help you then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741376/serialization-of-arraylist-containing-multiple-objects-doesnt-save-object-stat

Comment: Oh, do you have problems with adding the objects to the arraylist?

Comment: read few stuffs on arraylist but got confused lol

Comment: well I see someone has beat me to the answer. Read it, it should clear up using the arraylist class for you. It's well written :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write logic in main(), that logic should :

- Create Company Objects
- Add Company Objects to ArrayList
- Read Contents from ArrayList
- Write Contents to File

Use following main() code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            List<Company> companyList = new ArrayList<Company>();

            Company c1 = new Company("Test Company","111",111,89077.0);
            companyList.add(c1);
            Company c2 = new Company("Non Test Company","22",222,077.0);
            companyList.add(c2);

            String content=null;
            for(Company company:companyList)
            content+= company;

            File file = new File("D://output.txt");


            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much ...just a little question instead of hard coded data like Company c1 = new Company("Test Company","111",111,89077.0); can i take data in variable that the every time user inputs and pass variable instead..

Comment: Yes you can fetch data from input also. Instead of hardcode data, you can always fetch data from other sources (like Database, UI) and add that data to list.  Hope above code solves your purpose.